# Nested JSON into a ListActivity

Tags: android, json, listview

I have some nested JSON as following.

```
    {
      "status": 1,
      "data": [
        {
          "iMainServiceId": 1,
          "main": "NAILS",
          "sub": [
            {
              "iSubServiceId": 1,
              "vName": "Manicure",
              "fPrice": 15,
              "vDuration": "20 Minutes"
            },.......
]
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I want to get  this data shown in a ListActivity.
In this i want firstarray as a header in listview.and another array as data.
I am confused how to apply two different ArrayAdapters to this.

What should I do for  two different ArrayLists?
How should I use ArrayAdapters for this?

Comment: You can make the two ArrayList into one ArrayList. Then you can use that ArrayList to make the adapter

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the json as like below and use one `ArrayList<Products>` to get all the items and one adapter to view it!

```
{
    "products": [
      {
        "cat_id": "9",
        "position": "1",
        "sku": "wwww345"
      },
      {
        "cat_id": "9",
        "position": "2",
        "sku": "coof23"
      },
      {
        "cat_id": "9",
        "position": "3",
        "sku": "dde45"
      },
      {
        "cat_id": "9",
        "position": "4",
        "sku": "5555"
      },
      {
        "cat_id": "9",
        "position": "2",
        "sku": "coof23"
      },
      {
        "cat_id": "9",
        "position": "3",
        "sku": "dde45"
      },
      {
        "cat_id": "9",
        "position": "4",
        "sku": "5555"
      },
      {
        "cat_id": "9",
        "position": "1",
        "sku": "wwww345"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If there isn't any real need for all the list divisions, then flatten the list out.

```
List<JSONObject> prods = new ArrayList<>(); // Simple JSON list

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray prodCat_list = obj.getArray("prodCat_list");
for (int i = 0; i < prodCat_list.length(); i++) {
    JSONArray innerProds = prodCat_list.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("prods");
    for (int j = 0; j < innerProds.length(); j++) {
        JSONObject prod = innerProds.getJSONObject(j)

        // TODO: parse prod

        prods.add(prod);
    }
}

adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
    getContext(),  
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, // example layout
    prods);

listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```